# Append Data to A DolphinDB Table with R

Tags: r, sql-insert, bulkinsert, dolphindb

I have a DolphinDB table "t1". Now I want to append data.frame in R to "t1", how can I do? (Table schema cannot be taken into consideration. The number of columns of data.frame and t1 is the same.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dbUpload to upload data to DolphinDB server, and then append data to table “t1“.

```
> conn <- dbConnect(DolphinDB(), "localhost", 8848, "admin", "123456")
> ID=c(1L,2L)
> x=c(1,2)
> df=data.frame(ID,x)
> df
  ID x
1  1 1
2  2 2
> rs<-dbUpload(conn, c("t1"), list(df))
> rs_rt<-dbRun(conn, "t1")
> rs_rt
  ID x
1  1 1
2  2 2
> dbRun(conn, "loadTable('dfs://rangedb', `pt).append!(table(t1))")
[1] NA
> res_run<-dbRun(conn, "select * from loadTable('dfs://rangedb', `pt)")
> res_run
   ID          x
1   2 0.79314418
2   1 0.27108585
3   2 0.99476881
4   0 0.12563359
5   1 2.00000000
6   3 4.00000000
7   1 1.00000000
8   2 2.00000000
9   7 0.47339937
10  6 0.23528623
11  7 0.67196889
12  9 0.68633035
13  7 0.17768332
```